# String Interpolate is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have used `string` `replace` code as shown below.But it has an issue.Can you please tell me why?

**.ts**

```
 answerCode: string = 'answer_28903220';

 constructor(){}

let prompt = this.question.prompt.replace("{{this.answerCode}}", 
this.LookupAnswer(this.answerCode));//Not working: Output= "{{answer_28903220}} was born on:"

let prompt = this.question.prompt.replace("{{answer_28903220}}", 
               this.LookupAnswer(this.answerCode));//This is working fine:output= Sampath was born on:

 LookupAnswer(answerCode: string): string {
    let answer: string = '';
    _.some(this.answers, (value, key) => {
      if (value.questionCode == answerCode.substring(7)) {
        answer = value.answer;
        return true;
      }
    });
    return answer;
  }
```

Comment: How `string Interpolate` is related to the `typescript`? It must be an `angular` question, right? @Andrew Shepherd

Comment: Your confusion, and the subsequent solution, was to do with template literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals This is part of ECMA6 javascript, but is also a feature in typescript. You specifically tell us that the code example is in typescript.

I can't see any angular related stuff in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation on [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), replace your code with this:

```
let prompt = this.question.prompt.replace(`{{${this.answerCode}}}`,this.LookupAnswer(this.answerCode));
```

Replace `"` with backticks `` ` `` and enclose the variable with `${ }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead try with string template literals:

```
`${this.answerCode}`
```